# Identify vector element that contains ONLY certain strings in r

Tags: r, stringr

I have a long list of addresses. some of them only contains `CA` or `USA` or both.
What I need is I need to convert those to `NA` and leave other intact.

An example, I have the vector like below:

```
loc = c('CA, USA',
        'USA',
        '2 main st CA',
        '35 1st ave CA, USA',
        'CA')
```

What I need is:

```
loc = c( NA, NA, '2 main st CA',
        '35 1st ave CA, USA', NA)
```

This is just an example. The actual list is very long. 
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `ifelse(loc == "CA" | loc == "USA" | loc == 'CA, USA' | loc == 'USA, CA', NA, loc)`,  Will CA and USA occur always like that. Warning: This can fail also

Comment: Sonny's solution seems good to me, but it depends a bit on if there are variations of "USA, CA". For example, "CA, USA" seems plausible, and maybe you can have "USA,CA" (no space) as well. If you can single out all the alternatives, an ifelse statement seems like the best option

Comment: Maybe you can try `loc[nchar(gsub(c("USA|CA|CA, USA"), "", loc)) > 0]`.

Comment: yes. The address is very messy. USA, CA can happen. Some other variations like California.......  That give me a headache

Answer (score 0):

`nchar` will count the letters in each element of the vector of strings.

```
ifelse(nchar(string) > 7, string, NA) #to account for spaces

string<-c('CA, USA',
          'USA',
          '2 main st CA',
          '35 1st ave CA, USA',
          'CA')

string
[1] "CA, USA"            "USA"                "2 main st CA"      
[4] "35 1st ave CA, USA" "CA" 

ifelse(nchar(string) > 7, string, NA)
[1] NA                   NA                   "2 main st CA"      
[4] "35 1st ave CA, USA" NA
```

Or you can collapse all strings using:

```
st <- gsub(" ", "", gsub(",", "", string))
st
[1] "CAUSA"         "USA"           "2mainstCA"     "351staveCAUSA"
[5] "CA" 

replace(string, nchar(st) < 6, NA)
[1] NA                   NA                   "2 main st CA"      
[4] "35 1st ave CA, USA" NA
```

Or if you know exactly your criteria:

```
ifelse((grepl("^USA$", st) | grepl("^CA$", st) | 
grepl("^USACA$", st) | grepl("^CAUSA$", st)), NA, string)
[1] NA                   NA                   "2 main st CA"      
[4] "35 1st ave CA, USA" NA
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I feel there might be some other solutions that can apply more widely.  say, if the string is like `"united state of america" vs "main st.  boston"

Comment: Yeah these brute force solutions are sometimes highly specific. Good luck!

Comment: You may want to expand your matching criteria using `state.abb` or `state.name`, each of which are pre-loaded into R and contain the abbreviations and names of US states respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern  you want to retain always starts with a number, then you can use this

```
> loc[grep("^\\d", loc, invert = T)] <- NA
> loc
[1] NA     NA     "2 main st CA"   "35 1st ave CA, USA"   NA
```